# Generating WordCloud for a numerical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, word-cloud

I want to know if it is possible to generate a wordcloud on a numerical dataframe column whose values could be useful to interpret in a wordcloud.

I tried to do this :

```
text = df['tag'].value_counts().to_dict()

wordcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(text)
```

but got this error :

***TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable***

Anyone can help ?
Thanks

Comment: For numerical columns, it's more useful to analyze frequencies and discreptive statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your `tag` column to string: `.astype(str)`

```
import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'tag': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]})

text = df['tag'].astype(str).value_counts().to_dict()
wc = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(text)

plt.imshow(wc)
plt.show()
```

[image: Tag from numbers]